# How to refactor a class with multiple Lists + getters and setters for each list

Tags: java, refactoring

I have the following class:

```
public class RefactorMe {

  private static List<Event<Apple>> mAppleEventList = new ArrayList<Event<Apple>>();
  private static List<Event<Banana>> mBananaEventList = new ArrayList<Event<Banana>>();
  private static List<Event<Orange>> mOrangeEventList = new ArrayList<Event<Orange>>();

  public static List<Event<Apple>> getAppleList() {
    return mAppleEventList;
  }

  public static List<Event<Banana>> getBananaEventList() {
    return mBananaEventList;
  }

  public static List<Event<Orange> getOrangeList() {
    return mOrangeEventList;
  }

  public static void addAppleEvent(Event<Apple> pEvent) {
    mAppleEventList.add(pEvent);
  }

  public static void addBananaEvent(Event<Banana> pEvent) {
    mBananaEventList.add(pEvent);
  }

  public static void addOrangeEvent(Event<Orange> pEvent) {
    mOrangeEventList.add(pEvent);
  }

}
```

I tried refactoring it using the Visitor pattern but could not get it to work because of the generics.. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What's the goal of your refactoring?

Comment: I don't understand what you have tried to do and what does not work.

Comment: you could put your lists in map, is it possible for you to get `Apple.class` from `Event<Apple>` object?

Comment: @ammoQ The way it is now, each time a new Eventtype gets added (like Event<pineapple>) I need a new List and a 2 more methods, which I think is bad

Comment: @user902383 Yea I can get     Apple.class through event.getNewObject().getClass()

Comment: If your providing getters for the mutable lists, then you can just let the user add and subtract from the list itself, and not worry about add/remove methods.  However, this does violate encapsulation a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on @user902383 by using the Map here is a solution for you in Java 7:

```
public class RefactorMe {
  class Event<K> {
    public K getNewObject() {
      return null;
    }
  }

  private static Map<Class<?>, List<Event<?>>> eventLists = new HashMap<>();

  public static <E> List<Event<E>> getEventList(Class<E> clazz) {
    return (List) eventLists.get(clazz);
  }

  public static <E extends Event<E>> void addEvent(Event<E> pEvent) {
    Class<E> key = (Class<E>) pEvent.getNewObject().getClass();
    List<Event<?>> events = eventLists.get(key);
    if (events == null) {
      events = new ArrayList<>();
      eventLists.put(key, events);
    }
    events.add(pEvent);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesnt compile for me though: "Cannot cast from List<Event<?>> to List<Event<E>>" in the getEventList method and "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#1-of ? extends Object> to Class<E>" in the addEvent method.  I tried somethign similar before and I couldnt get around these compiler errors. Guess generics arent made for this task.

Comment: With generics, you sometimes needs to go round the compiler when writing very generic code using generics (sorry about wording).
This is a case of telling the compiler: "I know what I am doing. Leave me alone!" For that you need to use raw casts alas.